# asp.net mcv: How to send javascript array to c# controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have got this javascript array:

```
formatData = {
                            title: title,
                            start: startFormat,
                            end: endFormat
                        };
```

I would like to send the formatData to a method of the C# controller(and receive it as an array to post to the database):

```
//HomeController.cs
public ActionResult setReservation()
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        db.setReservations(reservation);
        return View();
    }
```

i have tried to send the javascript array with the following AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
                            url: '/Controller/HomeController',
                            type: 'POST',
                            contentType: 'application/json',
                            data: JSON.stringify({
                                formatData: formatData
                            }),

                        });
```

with no success. The browser "network" tab shows 404. What am I doing wrong? How can I catch the array from client-side javascript in the server side c# controller as a C# array-like? How could I attach the AJAX post to the `setReservation` method in the `c#` controller?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: formatData should pass to the Controller(HomeController.cs). In the controller, the data inside formData(title, start, end) must be passed to a method(setReservations) of an object(db) of another class(Database), where the data will be injected in a sql query string.

Comment: MVC Route dont consider Controller word while making the request additionally you need to pass Action Method or else use Route Attribute

Comment: Moreover handle the exception in the Ajax call.Else application may ran into trouble if the server exception occours

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the URL from your AJAX method is wrong. Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/SetReservation',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            formatData: formatData
                        }),

                    });
```

Then, in the controller, you need to have the list as a parameter for the action you want to use. Also, mark the action as [HttpPost]:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetReservation([FromBody]Reservation reservation)
    {
        Database db = new Database();
        db.setReservation(reservation);
        return View(); // you might want to redirect to another view instead
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Could you please explain why you use a List<Reservation> reservations as parameter? Shouldn't it be List<string>, because i am posting just a JSON string?

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I was confused by you saying that you want to receive an array. The JSON object that you send will be read as a C# object, if possible. So you can use a Model class instead of a list of strings. If you them in another format, maybe you should provide more details.

Comment: I'm sorry, my fault. I've edited the question with an explanation of the steps it should take. I hope it clarifies.